# Phaser time event won't loop

Tags: html, phaser-framework

I am trying to make a timer for my game but whatever I try to make it loop doesn't work and it will only go through once when the scene starts. This isn't my first scene in the game because I need it to start counting only during play.

```
create: function(){
        const self = this
        self.startTime = new Date();
        self.totalTime = 120;
        self.timeElapsed = 0;
        self.createTimer();
        self.gameTimer = this.time.addEvent({
            delay: 100,
            callback: self.updateTimer(),
            callbackScope: self,
            loop: true
        });
}


createTimer: function(){
        var me = this;
        me.timeLabel = me.add.text(600, 40, "00:00", {font: "40px Arial", fill: "#000000"});
       
        me.timeLabel.align = 'center';
},


updateTimer: function(){
        console.log("please")
        var me = this;
        var currentTime = new Date();
        //console.log(currentTime)
        var timeDifference = me.startTime.getTime() - currentTime.getTime();
        console.log(timeDifference)
        //Time elapsed in seconds
        me.timeElapsed = Math.abs(timeDifference / 1000);
        console.log(me.timeElapsed)
        //Time remaining in seconds
        //Convert seconds into minutes and seconds
        var minutes = Math.floor(me.timeElapsed / 60);
        var seconds = Math.floor(me.timeElapsed) - (60 * minutes);
        //Display minutes, add a 0 to the start if less than 10
        var result = (minutes < 10) ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
        console.log(result)
        //Display seconds, add a 0 to the start if less than 10
        result += (seconds < 10) ? ":0" + seconds : ":" + seconds;
        me.timeLabel.text = result;
}
```

I have tried using different methods but it either never repeats or it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, that you are **calling** the function `self.updateTimer` and **not *"passing"*** it to the `TimerEvent`, just change `callback: self.updateTimer()` to `callback: self.updateTimer` *(remove the brackets)* and it will work.

Here the `TimerEvent` creation:

```
    ...
    self.gameTimer = this.time.addEvent({
        delay: 100,
        // you need to pass the function
        callback: self.updateTimer,
        callbackScope: self,
        loop: true
    });
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks so much it's sometimes the most simple things that cause the most problems